# Custom delegate method called twice when trying to change tableview cell label from separate viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, protocols

I created a custom delegate method to change the label text of a tableview cell but it appears the method is being called twice.  After adding breakpoints it appears it's changing the variable that contains the new label text correctly, but then it calls it a second time, this time the variable is nil.  It's this second call that is changing the label.text but its nil.  this is how it's setup:

```
protocol ChangeInfoViewControllerDelegate {
    func changeInfoValue(vital: String)
}

//this class is where the new text value being created
class ManualVitalsInputViewController: UIViewController {

    let vitalVC = VitalsViewController()
    var delegate: ChangeInfoViewControllerDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = vitalVC
    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate.changeVitalValue(vital: "Test") //This gets called twice, 2nd time is nil
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

//this is the controller where the text is being changed
class VitalsViewController: UIViewController {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let vital = vitals[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.image = vital.image

        if changedManualVital != nil {
            cell.vitalTitleLabel.text = changedManualVital//where text should change to new text from delegate
        } else {
            cell.vitalTitleLabel.text = vital.title
        }

        return cell
    }
}

//where delegate used
extension VitalsViewController: ChangeInfoViewControllerDelegate {

    func changeVitalValue(vital: String) {
        self.changedManualVital = vital
    }
}
```

Any idea on why the delegate is called twice and how to only call once. Or if you have better suggestion to change a tableview cell label from another viewcontroller I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you present `vitalVC ` inside `ManualVitalsInputViewController` ??

Comment: No I don’t,  tue data is updated there but when going back to the vitals viewcontroller the data should be updated

Comment: then this `let vitalVC = VitalsViewController()` is another instance which won't work with delegate ,  also check events of button action

Comment: @Sh_Khan what would be the best way to set up this delegate?

Comment: ok illustrate the current flow of screens with vc names

Comment: The 'VitalsViewController' contains the cell label that need to be changed.  By pressing a button on the tableviewcell inside the 'VitalsViewController' it instantiates a storyboard with the 'ManualVitalsInputViewController'.  The 'ManualVitalsInputViewController' has the option to change the 'VitalsViewController' tableviewcell label text.  It can kind of be followed in example code

Comment: see answer.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of both

```
let vitalVC = VitalsViewController()
```

and

```
 self.delegate = vitalVC
```

Then when you instantiate the manual vc

```
 let vc = self.storyboard............... as! ManualVitalsInputViewController
 vc.delegate = self /// here is the actual link
 // present/push
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks a lot, been trying to figure this out for a while now.